# How can I download a file directly without a classic window "save as"?

Tags: web-applications, download

How can I create a button to download a general file directly, avoiding the classic window "save as" that appears after pushing the button.
Do you have any suggestion?

Thank you in advance for your support

Comment: You can't..... consider how nasty it would be if you could, and some malicious site used that method to overwrite core system files with malware

Comment: You can load a file using Ajax, it just won't save into the file system. You can do whatever you want to do with the downloaded binary content.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but that is not possible.

Actually I'm not sorry. I'm incredibly glad that it's not possible. :D

That "classic window" you want to avoid is an extremely important security feature that prevents you from unwittingly downloading malware to your computer.